# Using an <embed> tag with Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, embed, datacontext

I have a group of pdfs on another domain, and their urls in my Meteor app. My intention is to click a button, have it set a session variable and new data context, and have the associated pdf show up as an embedded object.

What's happening, is that if I directly reference it like below, it shows up the first time, but it doesn't update when I change data contexts.

```
<embed src="{{selectedSheet.docPath}}" type="application/pdf">
```

I've also tried embedding it all within a `{{#with}}` block, but in this case nothing will show up. It's definitely the `<embed>` that's breaking it -- if I remove that, this block works as expected.

```
{{#with selectedSheet}}     
    <embed src="{{docPath}}" type="application/pdf">
{{/with}}
```

I'm using this helper to get my `selectedSheet`, and I've verified that it's not an issue with the `Session.get` portion of it.

```
Template.bldgLevel.helpers({
    selectedSheet: function(){
        return Documents.findOne({"_id": Session.get("currentSheet")});
    }
});
```

Any help appreciated. I'm pretty new at this :)

Comment: What's `selectedSheet`? Is it taken from data context or a helper? The problem is most probably with the piece of code where it's defined, can you post that piece?

Comment: I'm using a helper. I've added that portion of the code above. Thanks!